# can't access dictionary values in jinja

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm creating a dict, it works fine. but after I create it i can't access the values of in the dict only the keys.
the dict:

```
- set_fact:
      dictonary_obj: |
        {% set record_info = dict() %}
        {% for item in list%}
        {% set _dummy = record_info.update({ item: 0 }) %}
        {%endfor%}
        "{{ record_info }}"
```

the access:

```
- debug:
      var: dictonary_obj[item] 
    with_items: "{{list}}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the quotation

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dictonary_obj: |
          {% set record_info = dict() %}
          {% for item in list1 %}
          {% set _dummy = record_info.update({ item: 0 }) %}
          {%endfor%}
          {{ record_info }}
```

For example, given the list

```yaml
    list1: [a, b, c]
```

the dictionary is

```yaml
  dictonary_obj:
    a: 0
    b: 0
    c: 0
```

and the loop works as expected

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: dictonary_obj[item]
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
```

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=a) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  dictonary_obj[item]: '0'
  item: a
ok: [localhost] => (item=b) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  dictonary_obj[item]: '0'
  item: b
ok: [localhost] => (item=c) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  dictonary_obj[item]: '0'
  item: c
```

---

Try the simpler option below which gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dictonary_obj: "{{ _dict|from_yaml }}"
      vars:
        _dict: |
          {% for item in list1 %}
          {{ item }}: 0
          {% endfor %}
```